# Maven Release plugin: Running specific preparationGoals & completionGoals in some modules of a project

Tags: maven, maven-release-plugin, multi-module

For the release process / preparation in my multi-module project I want to run additional goals in a selected set of modules (webapps). For example:

```
pom.xml (parent/root)
|-- common-module/pom.xml
|-- some-webapp/pom.xml
|-- some-other-module/pom.xml
|-- some-other-webapp/pom.xml
|-- (...more modules to follow)
```

The webapp-module(s) (should) use the [maven-frontend-plugin](https://github.com/eirslett/frontend-maven-plugin) to run some custom npm & grunt tasks (basically, mimic what checks & modifications release:prepare does in Java for our JS depdendencies).

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${version.release.plugin}</version>
    <configuration>
        <preparationGoals>frontend:grunt@update-static-resource-to-latest-stable frontend:npm@npm-update frontend:npm@npm-update</preparationGoals>
        <completionGoals>frontend:grunt@update-static-resource-to-latest frontend:grunt@check-static-resources-version</completionGoals>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Example for one of the goals (`phase none` so that it is not run anytime else):

```
<execution>
    <id>update-static-resource-to-latest-stable</id>
    <phase>none</phase>
    <goals>
        <goal>grunt</goal>
    </goals>
    <configuration>
        <arguments>latestStable</arguments>
    </configuration>
</execution>
```

So, I (thought that I) would need some preparationGoals & completionGoals to run when `mvn release:prepare` is invoked. Any other mechanism of triggering them during release-prepare is fine, however, I do not want to / cannot run additional commands manually.

**What have I tried:**

1: Adding the preparationGoals & completionGoals into the `build`-section of the specific module(s), but any config changes to the release-plugin need to be made to the root POM apparently.

2: Creating a [release profile](http://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/perform-mojo.html#releaseProfiles) per (webapp-)module, modifying the release plugin config to add the preparation & completion goals, but it release profiles seem only the be used during `release:perform`.